# Iphone ARC does it promote bad coding and memory management?

Tags: iphone, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

With the new Automatic Reference Counting, do you think this will encourage new iphone developers to ignore the cocoa memory management guidelines?, and thus promote bad coding?

Comment: Much of the useful detail of ARC is still under Apple NDA, which would make it kind of difficult to discuss fully at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To some extent, yes.  I think that memory management is already one of those things that you have to force your self to pay attention to.  Automating most of it will obscure it more from day to day programming and therefore make it easier to neglect the times when you do need to pay attention.

That said, the current system (non-ARC), is fairly problem prone as well.  Even when you do pay attention to reference counting you still, from time to time, find your self with leaks that are tricky to track down. At the end of the day I think that ARC is for the best.  It saves a lot of hassle, (Just look at the number of questions here on SO that are related to memory management) but you will have to be more aware of which cases ARC does not handle and avoid becoming overly dependent on it.

Answer (score 1):

We can't talk about specifics because of the NDA but...

I don't think this will help or hurt, at least from the standpoint of people understanding memory management.  They will have to follow naming conventions, and understand why when they name a method "create" they start getting compile warnings... they will still come to understand and use autorelease pools.  They may come to this understanding slower but they will find it eventually.

What I do think it will do, is make a LOT of programs memory use far more correct than it was.  It will improve runtime speed because of optimizations the compiler can do.   It will eliminate a lot of typing and *mis*typing.

Just as with any system where memory is mostly managed for you, there will still be leaks.  Oh yes, there will be leaks (a big part of the reason why people will understand ObjC memory management weather they want to or not)... but there will be a lot fewer crashes and in the end that is the best thing for the most important player in the whole system - the person running an application day to day.